# How to properly dynamically change information displayed in a website based on URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to JavaScript and React. I seem to be stuck on this question, I have found information but I think that this is not what I'm really looking for perhaps someone can shed some light on the matter.

So what I'm really looking for is a way to create a "mold" page of an node/react app that will display changing information based on the URL a user submits. Say for example look at facebook (or even stackoverflow) one click on a profile of friends 'y' then the url changes to facebook.com/friends-y and if we choose another person it then changes. Thus I believe that's how they must know how to fill their template using the info provided from that URL with names pictures etc.

I saw that a blog suggests to use [route](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/) another suggest using [url queries more so](https://medium.com/@BjornKrols/tutorial-dynamic-content-via-url-query-parameters-in-vue-js-d2df19b66633) (which I don't know how to read them once given or how to render them say such as with a onChange event sort of thing when say you click on something inside the page).

My question is: Are any of this methods useful, should I combine them I seen websites that uses both or is there another industry standard that i haven't  found and perhaps comes with react?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to have a single component that changes its contents based on the current url, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i assume that you have multiple component and you want to change from one component to another component via url. so you have to install react router dom

```
npm install --save react-router-dom
```

and after then import Router, Route, Link,  Switch (whatever you want) from react-router-dom and give route to component inside router tag .... i mention below in my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './component/login';
import User from './component/user';
import Signup from './component/signup';
import Notfound from './component/notfound';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link,  Switch} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      loggedIn : false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>


      <div className="App">
        <ul className="nav nav-pills">
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/login">LogIn</Link>
          </li>
          <li>  
            <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/user">User</Link>
          </li>
          </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/user" component={User} onEnter={this.requireAuth}/>
          <Route path="*" component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>

      </div>
      </Router> 
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**note :** in my code i have total 5 component in my project
    Login,
    User,
    Signup,
    NotFound,
    Home

for more router information you can check in this site. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './Components/Home/App'
import Digital from './Components/DigitalStrat/Digital-Strat';
import ServiceLines from './Components/Serviceline/ServiceLines';
import Operations from './Components/OperationTransformation/Operations- 
Transformation';
import WhyUs from './Components/WhyUs/Why-us';
import Mission from './Components/Mission/Mission';
import OurGroup from './Components/OurGroup/OurGroup';
import Team from './Components/Team/Team';
import Projects from './Components/Projects/Projects';
import Research from './Components/Research/Research';
import News from './Components/News/News';
import Locations from './Components/Location/Locations';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import NewsDetails from "./Components/NewsDetails/newsDetails";
import i18n from './js/i18n'
import { sliderArrow } from './js/sliderArrow';
import { menu } from './js/menu';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import Coockies from './Components/Cookies/Cookies';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
      }
    }
    render() {
        return this.props.children
    }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>

    <Switch>
    <ScrollToTop>
    <Route exact path = "/" component = {App}  />
    <Route exact path='/index.html' component={App}/>
    <Route exact path='/Digital-Strategies.html' component={Digital} />
    <Route exact path='/Service-Lines.html' component={ServiceLines} />
    <Route exact path='/Operations-Transformation.html' component= 
    {Operations}/>
    <Route exact path='/inside-the-company.html' component={WhyUs}/>
    <Route exact path='/Mission.html' component={Mission}/>
    <Route exact path='/Our-group.html' component={OurGroup}/>
    <Route exact path='/Team.html' component={Team}/>
    <Route exact path='/Projects.html' component={Projects}/>
    <Route exact path ='/Research-Development.html' component = {Research}/>
    <Route exact path='/News.html' component={News}/>
    <Route exact path='/news-details.html/:slug' component={NewsDetails}/>
    <Route exact path='/Locations.html' component={Locations}/>
    <Route exact path='/cookies' component={Coockies} />
    </ScrollToTop>
    </Switch>

  </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
  registerServiceWorker();
```

This is the basic way to route the project. Feel free to ask question.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle routing in React is with [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

With this sort of (virtual) routing there are two main ways that routing needs to be handled.

**1.** The first is by rendering different components when the url changes—for example rendering a `<Home/>` component for `"/"` and an `<About/>` component for `"/about"`.

An example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
                <Route path="/about" component={ About }/>
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**2.** The second case, which I believe your question specifically addresses, is rendering the same component with different data depending on the url—for example having a `<Profile/>` component but changing its data for `"/profiles/1"` vs `"/profiles/2"`.

An example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            profileData: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const currentId = this.props.match.params.id;
        const prevId = prevProps.match.params.id;

        if (currentId !== prevId) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }

    async fetchData() {
        const profileId = this.props.match.params.id;

        const profileData = await fetch(`http://example.com/api/profiles/${profileId}`);

        this.setState({
            profileData
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { profileData } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{ profileData.name }</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Profile);
```

Where the containing parent component of `<Profile/>` has a `<Route/>` that looks like this:

```js
<Route path="/profiles/:id" component={ Profile }/>
```

Which is important so that the `id` is in `this.props.match.params`.

Note that in the above example the way to check what data to use to populate the view is by checking the `:id` parameter in the url. Since information about the url is passed to the `<Profile/>` component as a prop, we can check if the url changes in `componentDidUpdate` and get new data if there was a change.

**Finally,** both of these involve a bit of setup with React Router (basically just wrapping your `<App/>` in a `<Router/>`) but the documentation should help with that: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello @Henry Woody I have another question I hope its ok to ask just this one time. It is someone related to the above but now I need to pass info though the state. Here is the link[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182871/how-to-properly-work-with-router-using-history-to-pass-variables)  to the question if you could help me in any way I would appreciate it.
Best